# zookeeper server will or not ack when network partition hanppens?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

for example, we have 5 zookeeper server in quorum mode. Client c1 succeeded connectting to server s1 and sent a update request r1 to it, and server s2 updated the r1 too. Now if we get another server do the same update, the  client c1 will get the ack from server s1. But before c1 get the ack, if the network partition happens and c1 change to connect to s2, will s2 take over the ack job for s1?(because it was supposed to belong s1.)

Comment: or it just omit the request and go on?

Comment: nobody got it ?